# GraphQL Refuse connection after deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, graphql

I've been trying to run a MERN stack app on Heroku in which I am using both Express and GraphQL.
Express for authentication and updates. GraphQL for fetching data for login options (which school you want to sign in to) & save data to React.Context upon login that is related to the user.

I finished the proposed part of the project and deployed the app to Heroku for testing and gathering feedback.

- The app builds successfully
- Environment variables for mongodb_uri is provided

The problem is when I open the app, the front disappears after a few seconds when the server responds that the [GraphQL connection is refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wSpM.png). However, the app running on my pc running perfectly fine with `nodemon` using  `concurrently`.

I am totally hopeless since:

- The app using CORS
- graphiql is false

Procfile contains the proper path to the server app and on the front proxy included to connect to 8080 as the app running on 3000.

Heres related code example for the front:

```
// index.js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql'
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client} >
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And the back:

```
// connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/unimeetingsapp', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
mongoose.connection.on('open', ()=>{
    console.log('Connected to Database')
});

// heroku
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("../client/build"));
}
  
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
//app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//////////////////////
// Routes
//////////////////////

// user Auth
app.use("/api", userAuth);
// user Events
app.use("/userevent", addEvent);
app.use("/userevent", confirmEvent);
app.use("/userevent", notification);
// org Auth
app.use("/api/org", orgAuth);
// org Events
app.use("/api/org", register);

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: false
}))
```

I have not a clue anymore as if I enable graphiql I can access it just by putting url+/graphql so the ports are probably not the problem, and if I miss something in Procfiles Heroku would throw an error log.

I think the server gets the request for the options to load before it would fire up so it just [refuses to connect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wSpM.png)
Any hint on how to solve that if that could be the problem?

I request the data with graphql from react-apollo in functional component and this is how I print on the front (coming from props):

```
        var data = schoolsData;
        if(data.loading) {
            return (<option > Loading Options ...</option>)
        } else {
            return data && data.schools.map(school => {
                return(
                <option key={school.id} value={school.id}>{school.name}</option>
                )
            })
        }
        
    }
```

[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wSpM.png):
[image]

Comment: Add falisafe condition before doing it, `data && data.schools && data.schools.map` and handle the condition where you are missing the `schools`

Comment: Thanks, now the page stays still, but GraphQL refuses the connection the same way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this and let me know its working fine:

```
if (data.loading) {
  return (<option > Loading Options ...</option>)
} else {
  if (data && data.schools) {
    data.schools.map(school => {
      return (
        <option key={school.id} value={school.id}>{school.name}</option>
      )
    })
  }else{
    return (<option > Data issue, School is missing! </option>)
  }
}
```

you said connection refused after deployment it's because you are using `localhost:8080` as server URL, try to replace it with the deployed server URL.

```
// index.js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '<server URL>/graphql' // Need to replace <server URL> with server URL
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client} >
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Yes, it returns "Data issue..."  instead of options from db

Maybe I should remove the instant GQL request from the component and write in express async... maybe the request so immediate the server cant handle it?

Comment: If that is something feasible for you, you can do it, as I mentioned above, if you are using localhost, it might cause that issue as well, if you have a separate URL for the deployed server try to replace it and check.

Comment: I dont see the point in that ...after deploying the app that localhost should be the new localhost... if you know what I mean. But since myapp.herokuapp/graphql is reachable when graphiql is on it makes sense... I'm deploying atm

Comment: Got it now, both your react and node servers are in Heroku and within the Heroku environment, you should be able to get the `localhost:8080`, for the server. if that's the case it looks like a data issue.

Comment: Now the app does not return anything :D
But it definitely does the request  with status code 200, but returns empty object

Comment: After changing stuff, error handling on the front went wrong since GraphQL sometimes sends data.loading: false meanwhile still has no data... fixed.  Automatic login needs to be reworked though. Thank you very much!